# wsdl : The term 'wsdl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, .net-framework, c#, mono-framework

How to use the `wsdl` command from Windows 10?

```
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> wsdl http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx
wsdl : The term 'wsdl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ wsdl http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.a ...
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wsdl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\thufir>
```

I don't have admin access.  System info:

```
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.14393.1944
InstanceId       : d740419c-8824-4cf5-a0cb-3b26437406bb
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-CA
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace



PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1944
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.1944
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\Users\thufir>
```

Oddly, the command [works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48854482/262852) on Linux PowerShell, but **not from Windows 10 as here**.

*For the sake of privacy, I changed the powershell prompt:
     function prompt { "thufir >" }
The `pwd` is of the form:
`C:\Users\<username> >`*

Comment: I tried from in powershell itself and the regular cmd command prompt.  This is on Windows.  (I'll update the q to show that, pardon.)  Not Linux.

Comment: for this:  Windows 10 is the OS.  I sometimes use Linux, but this q is plain-vanilla Windows.  full path for...?  I updated the q with path info at the bottom.

Comment: Not whether full .NET is installed @James, will check. Thx.  Didn't know about svcutil.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have .NET SDK installed? First you need to check whether you have the wsdl.exe available at the below location :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\<version folder>\bin folder
```

if not, install the .NET SDK from MSDN web site.

Also, wsdl command expects the WSDL url of the web service, looks like you are passing the ASMX url - which might not help. In this case the WSDL URL will be http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl