# svcutil.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, shell-script, .net-framework

Looking to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6420354/262852) `SvcUtil.exe` [instead](https://superuser.com/q/1296406/55747) of the `wsdl` command.

Where is `SvcUtil.exe`?

```
thufir>
thufir> ls 'C:\Program Files\'


    Directory: C:\Program Files


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
da----       2016-10-26   1:40 PM                7-Zip
d-----       2016-10-04  11:06 AM                Common Files
d-----       2017-08-15   4:31 AM                Intel
d-----       2018-01-13  12:19 AM                Internet Explorer
da----       2017-08-15   7:56 AM                Managed Defender
d-----       2016-10-04  11:03 AM                Microsoft Analysis Services
da----       2017-08-15   8:04 AM                Microsoft Office
da----       2017-08-15   7:39 AM                Microsoft Policy Platform
d-----       2016-10-04  11:06 AM                Microsoft SQL Server
d-----       2016-10-04  11:07 AM                Microsoft.NET
d-----       2016-10-26   1:19 PM                MSBuild
d-----       2017-08-15   8:04 AM                Oracle
d-----       2017-08-15   4:30 AM                Realtek
d-----       2016-10-26   1:19 PM                Reference Assemblies
d-r---       2017-11-28   1:11 AM                Windows Defender
d-----       2017-09-16   6:16 AM                Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection
d-----       2017-08-15   7:56 AM                Windows Firewall Configuration Provider
d-----       2017-10-24  12:23 AM                Windows Mail
d-----       2017-08-16  12:21 AM                Windows Media Player
d-----       2016-07-16   4:47 AM                Windows Multimedia Platform
d-----       2016-07-16   4:47 AM                Windows NT
d-----       2018-02-20  12:04 AM                Windows Photo Viewer
d-----       2016-07-16   4:47 AM                Windows Portable Devices
d-----       2016-07-16   4:47 AM                WindowsPowerShell


thufir>
```

This means that `SvcUtil` isn't [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4876374/262852)?

update:

*The [fine manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) says it should be at that location, so probably not installed.*

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Where is SvcUtil.exe?

It is not installed on your computer.

From the link in your question:

> The ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool can be found at the Windows SDK installation location, specifically, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin

You need to install the Windows SDK (which is included as part of Visual Studio).

And:

> **Using SvcUtil.exe**
>
> You can use SvcUtil.exe to generate a proxy and the configuration
>   settings that define how to connect to the native endpoint for the
>   Dynamics GP service. This may be necessary if Visual Studio cannot
>   create the appropriate entries in the app.config for the service
>   reference you add to your project. Complete the following procedure to
>   use SvcUtil.exe to generate a proxy and configuration settings.
>
> 1. Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt window.
>
>    Click the Start menu, click Visual Studio, click Visual Studio
>      Tools, and then click Visual Studio Command Prompt.
> 2. Set the current folder.
>
>    In the command prompt, se t the current folder to the location where
>      you want the generated proxy and configuration files to be created.
> 3. Run SvcUtil.exe to generate the output files.
>
>    To use svcutil.exe you need to provide the URL of the native endpoint
>      for the Dynamics GP service and the namespace of the service reference
>      you added to your Visual Studio project. Typically, this is
>      "DynamicsGPService".
>
>    Enter the following on a single line and then press Enter.
>
>    ```
>    svcutil.exe http://<machine>:<port>/Dynamics/GPService /n:*,DynamicsGPService
>    ```
> 4. Use the generated files.
>
>    If you choose to, you can use the generated proxy in your project.
>      You can also use the generated configuration settings in the
>      app.config for a Visual Studio project. In a text editor, open the
>      output.config file created by SvcUtil.exe. Copy the
>       node from the ouput.config file and add it to
>      the app.config file of your Visual Studio project.

Source [Using SvcUtil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623148.aspx)